# How to accelerate specific process on Ubuntu

Tags: performance, ubuntu, backup, plesk, plesk-onyx

I'm executing `pleskbackup` on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS‬ server to create a full backup.

This task has already been running for over half a day now. While the server isn't nearly working to capacity.

```
CPU: 1.5% (of 800%, 8 cores)
Memory: 3.9% (626 MB of 15.6 GB)
```

Is there any way to give this specific task more resources for speed it up?

I've set the priority already to the highest via `htop`.

– Thanks in advance.

Comment: `taskset` may help you by affine  the running process to a dedicated core . and `nice` to set priority,

Comment: Thanks. I've re-checked this. It's running und nice +19 (priority 39) and all CPU cores `0-7`

Comment: Regardless of process priority, if the machine is not busy, lower priority processes get CPU time. Changing priority probably doesn't do anything. BTW, to change the priority of running process, use "renice" command.
If you are using FTP, take a look at the destination to see the sign of trouble.